# Local postgresql server and creating new user on linux

Tags: postgresql

I installed `postgresql` via synaptic on ubuntu.

Now I dont know how to create new user, run server and  create it in `pgAdmin3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to create a postgres user called $USER:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
```

Creating a DB with the same name as your user name makes things easier. It becomes your default DB.

```
createdb $USER
```

Use this to set a password for USER. This must be done for pgadmin3 to work.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password USER
```